# Flux query(Influxdb2) to sum the dynamic column values

Tags: influxdb, flux

The stock data is stored in InfluxDB2, the below query helps to get the latest OI value for selected(using Grafana's multi select functionality) stocks at 1 hour window timeline.

```
import "array"

data = ["BANKNIFTY2370644500PE", "BANKNIFTY2370644400PE"] //consider this is a Grafana variable 

from(bucket: "mybucket")
  |> range(start: v.timeRangeStart, stop: v.timeRangeStop)
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_measurement"] == "3min")
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_field"] == "oi")
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["symbol"] =~ /(BANKNIFTY2370644400PE|BANKNIFTY2370644500PE)/) //grafava variable replace here
  |> aggregateWindow(every: 1h, fn: last, createEmpty: false)
  |> pivot(rowKey:["_time"], columnKey: ["symbol"], valueColumn: "_value")
  |> map(fn: (r) => ({  r with _value: r["BANKNIFTY2370644500PE"] + r["BANKNIFTY2370644400PE"], _time:r._time,  _field:"Put OI" })) //TODO: remove the hard coded stock names
```

The above query works perfectly fine, however notice the last line where the stock names are hard-coded. Would like to remove the hard-coded stock names instead of that use the Grafana variable. That would help me to apply different stocks from Garafana multi select variable.

Here is the above query result.
[image]

I tried below flux query to replace the hard-coded value,

```
import "array"

data = ["BANKNIFTY2370644500PE", "BANKNIFTY2370644400PE"] //consider this is a grafana varibale 

from(bucket: "mybucket")
  |> range(start: v.timeRangeStart, stop: v.timeRangeStop)
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_measurement"] == "3min")
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_field"] == "oi")
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["symbol"] =~ /(BANKNIFTY2370644400PE|BANKNIFTY2370644500PE)/) //grafava variable replace here
  |> aggregateWindow(every: 1h, fn: last, createEmpty: false)
  |> pivot(rowKey:["_time"], columnKey: ["symbol"], valueColumn: "_value")
  //|> map(fn: (r) => ({  r with _value: r["BANKNIFTY2370644500PE"] + r["BANKNIFTY2370644400PE"], _time:r._time,  _field:"Put OI" }))
  |> map(fn: (r) => ({
    r with
    _value: data |> array.map(fn: (x) => r[x])
      |> reduce(fn: (r, accumulator) => ({sum: r._value + accumulator.sum}), identity: {sum: 0})
  }))
```

However the query has been failed and following error reported. Looking forward your help to resolve the error.

> error @15:35-15:46: expected string but found int (argument x)
> (argument fn) error @16:10-16:97: expected stream[{A with _value:
> int}] but found [{A with _value: int}] (array) (argument tables) error
> @13:6-17:6: [{A with _value: int}] (array) is not Record (argument
> tables)